# Cómo editar el css de una página que se encuentra dentro de un iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Es una página de la misma página web, ya intenté de todo pero no me funciona, qué puedo hacer?

```
<iframe id="link" src="https://www.google.com">pagina de ejemplo</iframe>

<style>
#link div{
/* estilos */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código solo me ha funcionado si ambas páginas son del mismo dominio, en este caso sencillo solo haces un append directamente al Head del iframe al que haces referencia.

```
$('#link').load( function() {
   $('#link').contents().find("head")
   .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .my-class{display:none;}  </style>"));
});
```